# What is the default font-size in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I looked at [this website](http://www.iecss.com/ie-9.css) to see the default styling that IE 9 uses. The body selector looks like this

```
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

I would I have guessed that a font-size should have been specified here but it isn't.
So what is the default font-size that IE 9 is using?

Comment: I think desktop browsers have historically used 16px as their base font size. I don’t actually know whether IE 9 uses that, although I imagine it does, because on my websites I define all fonts in ems, so they’re relative to the base font size, and I haven’t noticed IE 9 rendering them at different sizes than other browsers.

Comment: So is this base font-size build into the broswer in some way because there is no default base font-size specified in the default CSS for IE ?

Comment: @user2658578 Yes, probably.

Comment: @user2658578: yup. There has to be a base font size that the document starts with, because in CSS, all HTML elements (including `<html>`) can have their font size set in ems, which makes their actual size relative to their parent element. As the `<html>` element has no parent element, there has to be some size for everything else to be relative to.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

font-size is being set on every element in that stylesheet in `em`

eg

```
h3 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1em 0;
    page-break-after: avoid;
}

h4 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1.33em 0;
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

Comment: What about the `p` element? There is no `font-size` attribute.

Comment: @Vector: but `em` is a relative font size, so you’d need to know what the root element’s font size is (in absolute terms) to work out what `1.17em` means for the `h3`.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The default font size should be what ever you set it.
If you do not set a default font size the web browser will depict the users default settings, meaning the answer to this question is unable to be answered. The settings between IE, Mozilla, Opera, Crome, and Safari are all different.

Never trust information from the user, set the settings yourself.

Comment: ... and if the user is vision-impaired and can't read text at the size you set, tough on them, because who cares about half-blind people anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In IE, the default font size is set by the user with View > Text Size. I think "medium", the "default default", is 16px.

Other browsers have a similar in-browser setting, though in most browsers other than IE, it's buried deep inside option menus.

I would encourage you to make all your font sizes relative. That way, a user who has poor eyesight can increase the font size and everything should increase proportionately. Or a user who has a high-resolution screen and wants to cram as much text on it as possible can decrease the font size.

Note that if you use relative font sizes, you may have to set the sizes of other things on the screen in em's rather than px's, or use some other technique to make them size to fit the text, as at that point you don't know what the text size is. Sure, it's easier to lay out a screen with fixed font sizes.

Personally I regularly curse people who set fixed screen widths that are wider than my display, so now I have to scroll back and forth to read. Like, what, they assume that just because they have their monitor set to 2,000 pixels wide, that everyone else in the world does or should do the same?

Answer (score -1):

The traditional default font size in IE is 12pt (= 1pc). Although its meaning in pixels originally depended on DPI settings, IE 9 seems to consistently apply the CSS3 correspondence, which makes 12pt equal to 16px. This in turn implies that px does not necessarily correspond to device pixel.